# bash script with regular expression

Tags: regex, bash

I'm a newbie to bash and I'm trying to write a script to do maintenance on a LXC host and it's containers which you can find in my [github project](https://github.com/pegasusict/plat).
At the moment I'm trying to get the names of the containers into two arrays: $active_containers and $inactive_containers. The regular expression I've built is based on the following:

> [Enforce valid container names](https://github.com/stgraber/lxd/commit/1f653f73f681dd2afd6d71d1a953b8c510445721)
>
> This requires all container names to:
>      - be between 1 and 63 characters long
>      - be made solely of alphanumerical characters and hyphens
>      - not start with a numerical character or hyphen
>      - not end with an hyphen

I know my regex isn't perfect yet, it looks for 3-63 chars for now.

My test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bashbased
active_containers="$(lxc list -c ns | grep RUNNING)"
echo $active_containers
findcontainers='\b(a-zA-Z{1}a-zA-Z0-9\-{,61}a-zA-Z0-9{1})\b'
echo $active_containers | sed -e $findcontainers
echo "Containers found: $active_containers"
```

FYI: the output of command "lxc list -c ns":

```
+-------------+---------+
|    NAME     |  STATE  |
+-------------+---------+
| linuxserver | RUNNING |
+-------------+---------+
| websites    | RUNNING |
+-------------+---------+
```

current result:

```
| linuxserver | RUNNING | | websites | RUNNING |
sed: -e expression #1, char 37: unterminated address regex
```

The result I'd like to get:

```
$active_containers(0): "linuxserver"
$active_containers(1): "RUNNING"
$active_containers(2): "websites"
$active_containers(3): "RUNNING"
```

I've been searching through stackoverflow and manuals of (e)grep, sed and awk but can't find what I'm doing wrong..

My humble apologies if I've made a duplicate question.
edit:
I would grately appreciate if somebody could tell me what's wrong about my question that deserves a -1. I don't know what to fix/improve...

Comment: should probably be `"$findcontainers"`  bare variables are usually a mistake

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with your `sed`?

Comment: @PesaThe I'm trying to isolate the names of the containers so my script can send commands to the containers as well as pulling/pushing files to and from the containers.

Comment: @Jasen Does not seem to make a difference but left it in anyway just in case

Comment: it will make a difference if there ever are names containing spaces etc...

Comment: @Jasen: spaces are not allowed according to the "enforce valid container names" quote I placed in my post. I believe this has to do with dns compliance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
findcontainers='^[a-zA-Z0-9][-a-zA-Z0-9]*$'
echo "$active_containers" | grep "$findcontainers"
```

to match 3 to 63 charcters, and no hyphen in first or last position, depending on grep versions `{` must be escaped or not to have a special meaning.

```
findcontainers='^[a-zA-Z0-9][-a-zA-Z0-9]\{1,61\}[a-zA-Z0-9]$'
echo "$active_containers" | grep "$findcontainers"
```

otherwise use gnu grep with PCRE (`-P` perl regex)

```
findcontainers='^[a-zA-Z0-9][-a-zA-Z0-9]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]$'
echo "$active_containers" | grep -P "$findcontainers"
```

given lxc output, the pattern name may match because of `RUNNING` already filtered maybe following can help:

```
echo "$active_containers" | grep -Po "\b[a-zA-Z0-9][-a-zA-Z0-9]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9](?=\s*\| RUNNING)"
```

1. variables must be enclosed between double quotes when passed as argument to commands to avoid word splitting (splitted into multiple parameters).
2. the tool to filter matches is `grep`, `sed` is to make replacements.

   - `^` begin of line anchor matches empty string
   - `[`..`]` is character set, `-` in first position or last to add hyphen `-` to set otherwise defines a range of characters
   - `*` means 0 or more occurences
   - `$` end of line anchor matches empty string